# Hangman game in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, windows-forms-designer, designer

I was working on this hangman game in c# and so it's not working how I wanted.
The point of the game is next: When you start the game you need to open the .txt file where the words are written. When u load your .txt file with words game should show as many "*" as how many letters your randomly chosen word from the .txt file has. When u click on the button with the letter game should check if the chosen word has that letter in it if it has one or more chosen letters, "*" from the word should disappear and the chosen letter should show up, else our attempts should decrease for 1 and should show next picture in panel1.

I also want to set up the game so that only Cyrillic from the Serbian language can be used in the .txt file and the game itself.

**Now about the problem, everything is working fine except the code where the game checks if a word has a chosen letter. Another problem is space, there should be the possibility of guessing multiple words at once but when I add space between two or more words game use "_" for space as well as for other characters, I need space to not be replaced with "__"**

```
void NapraviLabels()
        {
           string cre = UzmiNasumicnuRijec();
           string recc = cre.Replace(" ", "");
           rec = recc.ToLower();
           char[] chars = rec.ToCharArray();
           int izmedju = 330 / chars.Length - 1;
           for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length - 1; i++)
           {
               foreach(char c in rec)
                {
                    if( c == ' ')
                    {
                        labels[i].Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        labels.Add(new Label());
                        labels[i].Location = new Point((i * izmedju) + 10, 120);
                        labels[i].Text = "_";
                        labels[i].Parent = groupBox2;
                        labels[i].BringToFront();
                        labels[i].CreateControl();
                    }
                }
           }
        }
        
        string UzmiNasumicnuRijec()
        {
            string listaRijeci = File.ReadAllText(@filePath);
            string[] rijeci = listaRijeci.Split('\n');
            Random r = new Random();
            return rijeci[r.Next(0, rijeci.Length -1)];
        }

        Button curButton = null;
        Label curLabel = null;
        private void slovo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedbtn = (Button)sender;
            Label lb = GetLBFromButton(clickedbtn);

            if (curButton == null)
            {
                // first button clicked
                curButton = clickedbtn;
                curLabel = lb;
                clickedbtn.Visible = false;
                curLabel.Visible = true;
                char slovo = curLabel.Text.ToLower().ToCharArray()[0];
                if (rec.Contains(slovo))
                {
                    char[] slova = rec.ToCharArray();
                    for (int i = 0; i < slova.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (slova[i] == slovo)
                            labels[i].Text = slovo.ToString();
                    }
                    foreach (Label l in labels)
                        if (l.Text == "_") return;
                    MessageBox.Show("Победили сте!", "Честитамо");
                    Reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Слово које сте унели се не налази у појму!");
                    NacrtajDijeloveTijela((DjeloviTijela)kolicina);
                    kolicina++;
                    if (kolicina == 9)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Изгубили сте, појам је био: " + rec);
                        Reset();
                    }
                }
                curButton = null;
                curLabel = null;
            }
        }

private void pogodirec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == rec)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Победили сте!", "Честитамо");
                Reset();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Реч коју сте унели је погрешна!" , "Грешка!");
                NacrtajDijeloveTijela((DjeloviTijela)kolicina);
                kolicina++;
                if (kolicina == 10)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Изгубили сте, појам је био: " + rec);
                    Reset();
                } 
            }
        }
```

Comment: *"Another problem"*. You need to ask one question at a time. If you have two questions to ask, post them separately, providing all and only the information relevant to that problem.

Comment: You need to elaborate more as to what is currently happening and focus on one particular problem. In other words, it seems irrelevant to think in terms of “multiple” words if the current code fails on a single word. You stated that the game loads a file, and how you want to use Serbian language and more than one word and finally you state that… “_... everything is working fine except the code where the game checks if a word has a chosen letter.”_ … ? … Ok, what happens when the code checks if the word has a chosen letter? And what are you expecting to happen?